# Linux Sudo NoExec breaks timeout command

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I've been battling sudo into getting /bin/timeout to work alongside another permitted command.

For instance, what I'm trying to do is:

```
john ALL=(ALL,!ROOT) NOEXEC:NOPASSWD: /bin/timeout, /bin/xx
```

then permit john to use xx command with a timeout.

Understanding this is the function of the NOEXEC part of sudo, was there a proper way to target this issue instead of simply allowing exec without allowing them to use timeout to proxy into running another unpermitted command?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are actually changing user when you run `xx`, but I'm assuming it is to user jill.

You seem to have 3 commands to play with: `timeout`, `xx`, and `sudo`.
If you allow jack to run `sudo -u jill timeout 99 sudo ... xx` then you can use the 2nd sudo to put back the NOEXEC. Something like:

```
jill ALL=(jill)     NOEXEC:NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xx
jack ALL=(ALL,!ROOT)NOEXEC:NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xx
jack ALL=(ALL,!ROOT)  EXEC:NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/timeout [0-9] sudo -u jill xx
```

and then you can do

```bsh
sudo -u jill timeout 5 sudo -u jill xx
```

and user jill will have NOEXEC set for `xx`.

Comment: Awesome, so the concern here was the fact that timeout won't have the permission scope to kill the command executed one the user changes, ex. `timeout 1 sudo -u jill sleep 20`

I'll try out the idea of filling the whole command out, perhaps that'll do the trick. I just fear that someone can easily escape their shell doing something like sudo -u jill "timeout 20 xx && /usr/bin/unauthorisedCommandHere"